# View of content is cut out when using transition maxHeight in html css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const jsonData = [
        { text: "TITLE 1", children: [
                { text: "subtitle 1",  children: [
                        { text: "sub subtitle 1a" },
                        { text: "sub subtitle 1b" } ] }, 
                { text: "subtitle 2", children: [
                        { text: "sub subtitle 2a"},
                        { text: "sub subtitle 2b"}
                ] },
                { text: "subtitle 3" }
            ] },
        { text: "TITLE 2", children: [
                { text: "subtitle 1" },
                { text: "subtitle 2" },
                { text: "subtitle 3" } ] },
        { text: "TITLE 3", children: [
                { text: "subtitle 1", children: [
                        { text: "sub subtitle 1a" },
                        { text: "sub subtitle 1b" } ] },
                { text: "subtitle 2" }
            ]
        }
    ];

    const treeContainer = document.getElementById("tree");

    function createTree(treeData, parentElement) {
        treeData.forEach(item => {
            const listItem = document.createElement("li");
            const toggleButton = document.createElement("button");
            toggleButton.innerText = item.text;

            let sublist; // Define sublist variable here

            if (item.children) { // still have children
                sublist = document.createElement("ul");
                
                
                // toggleButton.style.content = "▼";
                createTree(item.children, sublist);
                listItem.appendChild(toggleButton);
                listItem.appendChild(sublist);
            } else { // no more children
                const toggleButton2 = document.createElement("button");
                toggleButton2.innerText = item.text;
                listItem.appendChild(toggleButton2);
            }

            toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                if (sublist) {
                    toggleButton.classList.toggle("toggled");
                    
                        if(sublist.style.maxHeight){
                            sublist.style.maxHeight = null;
                        } else {

                sublist.style.maxHeight = sublist.scrollHeight + "px";
                           

                        }
                 
                }
               

            });

            

            parentElement.appendChild(listItem);
        });
    }

    createTree(jsonData, treeContainer);
});
```

```css
/* Apply basic styling */
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
}

li > button {
    background: blue;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
   
}


  
li > ul > li > button {
    background: yellow;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
}

li > ul > li > ul > li > button {
    background: green;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
}


button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

/* Add icon for the toggle button */
button:has(+ ul)::after {
    content: "\25BC";
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/* Style the button when it's toggled */
button.toggled:has(+ ul)::after {
    content: "\25B2";
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Site  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>



  <div id="tree"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I have the html ,css js codes as above.

[image]

when i click the title 1, it expands using the maxheight attributes

[image]

when i click the subtitle 1, it still expand its content but the subtitle 3 is being cut out from the view.

how to make the subtitle 3 still in view after expanding subtitle 1, etc

ive tried chatgpt / bard, but no use.

Answer (score 0):

What @Vasilis G suggested was actually a good point. However, his answer has an issue when only targeting a single node

`sublist.childNodes[0].scrollHeight`

One way to solve that issue is by creating a recursive function to get the scrollHeight of each child node that way we're not focusing on a single node.

```
const getNodesTotalHeight = function (list) {
   let total = 0;
   if(list.length > 0) {
     list.forEach(function(item){
        total += item.scrollHeight;
        if(item.childNodes.length > 1){
           total += getNodesTotalHeight(item.childNodes)
        }
       })
      }
            
    return total;   
 }
```

Here's an updated working solution:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const jsonData = [
        { text: "TITLE 1", children: [
                { text: "subtitle 1",  children: [
                        { text: "sub subtitle 1a" },
                        { text: "sub subtitle 1b" } ] }, 
                { text: "subtitle 2", children: [
                        { text: "sub subtitle 2a"},
                        { text: "sub subtitle 2b"},
                        { text: "sub subtitle 2c"},
                        { text: "sub subtitle 2d"},
                        { text: "sub subtitle 2e"},
                        { text: "sub subtitle 2f"},
                        { text: "sub subtitle 2g"},
                        { text: "sub subtitle 2h"}
                ] },
                { text: "subtitle 3"}
            ] },
        { text: "TITLE 2", children: [
                { text: "subtitle 1" },
                { text: "subtitle 2" },
                { text: "subtitle 3" } ] },
        { text: "TITLE 3", children: [
                { text: "subtitle 1", children: [
                        { text: "sub subtitle 3a" },
                        { text: "sub subtitle 3b" } ] },
                { text: "subtitle 2" }
            ]
        }
    ];

    const treeContainer = document.getElementById("tree");

    function createTree(treeData, parentElement) {

        const getNodesTotalHeight = function (list) {
           let total = 0;
            if(list.length > 0) {
              list.forEach(function(item){
                  total += item.scrollHeight;
                  if(item.childNodes.length > 1){
                     total += getNodesTotalHeight(item.childNodes)
                  }
              })
            }
            
            return total;   
        }

        treeData.forEach(item => {
            const listItem = document.createElement("li");
            const toggleButton = document.createElement("button");
            toggleButton.innerText = item.text;

            let sublist; // Define sublist variable here

            if (item.children) { // still have children
                sublist = document.createElement("ul");
                
                
                // toggleButton.style.content = "▼";
                createTree(item.children, sublist);
                listItem.appendChild(toggleButton);
                listItem.appendChild(sublist);
            } else { // no more children
                const toggleButton2 = document.createElement("button");
                toggleButton2.innerText = item.text;
                listItem.appendChild(toggleButton2);
            }

            toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
               
                if (sublist) {
                    toggleButton.classList.toggle("toggled");
                    
                        if(sublist.style.maxHeight){
                            sublist.style.maxHeight = null;
                        } else {     
                            const totalNodesChildrenHeight = getNodesTotalHeight(sublist.childNodes)
                            sublist.style.maxHeight = sublist.scrollHeight + toggleButton.scrollHeight + totalNodesChildrenHeight + "px";
                        
                }
              }
            });

            

            parentElement.appendChild(listItem);
        });
    }

    createTree(jsonData, treeContainer);
});
```

```css
    /* Apply basic styling */
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
}

li > button {
    background: blue;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
   
}


  
li > ul > li > button {
    background: yellow;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
}

li > ul > li > ul > li > button {
    background: green;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
}


button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

/* Add icon for the toggle button */
button:has(+ ul)::after {
    content: "\25BC";
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/* Style the button when it's toggled */
button.toggled:has(+ ul)::after {
    content: "\25B2";
  }
```

```html
  <div id="tree"></div>
```

**NOTE:**
If you don't want to calculate the maxHeight you can simply set it to 'fit-content' like this:

`sublist.style.maxHeight = 'fit-content'`

Comment: it does work, however the transition effect is lost somehow. and there were some lagging when clicking the buttons

Comment: @EhsanRosdi I updated my answer. The effect is because you are using scrollHeight. You can update the transition in css if you want to fix the lagging. However, if you still want to use scrollHeight you could have a function to get the height from each child node. If my updated answer helps you please mark it as the correct answer :), thanks

Comment: @EhsanRosdi also if you dont want to calculate the maxHeight you can simply set it to 'fit-content' like this:  sublist.style.maxHeight = 'fit-content'

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account the scroll height of the sublist's child nodes, as well as the scroll height of the toggle button. So, you have to change the line:

```
sublist.style.maxHeight = sublist.scrollHeight + "px";
```

with the following:

```
let childLength = sublist.childNodes.length;
let childNodeHeight = sublist.childNodes[0].scrollHeight;
sublist.style.maxHeight = (sublist.scrollHeight + toggleButton.scrollHeight + (childLength * childNodeHeight)) + "px";
```

You can test the result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v5tgwk4s/1/).

Try adding more list items to a sublist to test if it's responding correctly.